# Quickest/most concise bash one-liner for extracting specified lines from a file

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to extract just the lines with specific line numbers from a file (I have about 20-50 line numbers, the file has 30,000 lines).  So far, the most concise way I've found to do this is e.g.:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {split("13193,15791,16891", A, ",")} NR in A' <file_name>
```

but it seems like I should be able to further reduce the amount of typing involved. I've looked at `sed` but I think I need an `-n` and a `-p` for each line number, also thought about `cat -n` with `grep` but it's more verbose than the above.  Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: Do you really type 20-50 line numbers into the command line argument?

Comment: Not by hand! I pasted them from another program, so the amount of typing is only a function of which command to use to get bash to recognise the numbers as line numbers in a file.

Comment: Sounds... clunky. ;) I think I personally would prefer to paste them into a file. A very short perl script would do the trick for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sed can be more concise:

```
sed -n "13193p;15791p;16891p" file_name
```

Comment: thanks, that's the sort of thing I was looking for. I need to brush up on my sed skills.

Answer (score 4):

Put the list of line numbers in a separate file, then

```
gawk 'FNR==NR {line[$1]; next} NR in line' line_numbers file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed?):

```
sed 's/$/p/' file_of_line_numbers | sed -nf - source
```